# What is the hero roster for 1v1 Limited Duel?

Tags: overwatch

I'm enjoying the new 1v1 Limited Duel mode introduced with Overwatch's Anniversary Update. However, I was curious about what the full list of selectable heroes for the mode was.

The in-game information isn't much help, only stating "*Limited hero pools*" and "*Unavailable hero: Lúcio*", but [online forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20755017984#post-1) tell me there are other unavailable heroes as well.

[image: In-game info about Limited Duel]

Comment: Do I need to point out that the screenshot gives you a list of heroes you can't play?  Granted, it's only **one** hero, but a list of one is still a list.

Comment: @Powerlord Lucio isn't the only restricted hero. You also are restricted from playing Torbjörn, D.Va, Reinhardt, Winston, Zarya, Lúcio, Mercy, and Symmetra

Comment: Basically anyone that would be obnoxious to play a 1v1 in because they'll try to hide, or the self heal, etc. Anything that would make games drag on too long, 1v1 is intended to be short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of testing, I've encountered the following heroes in 1v1 limited duel.

## Available Heroes

#### Offense

- [Genji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYDMr.jpg)
- [McCree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrGZK.jpg)
- [Pharah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0epuW.jpg)
- [Reaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q7wn.jpg)
- [Soldier 76](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Quhu.jpg)
- [Sombra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODd9c.jpg)
- [Tracer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhFTy.jpg)

#### Defense

- [Hanzo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6KaR.jpg)
- [Junkrat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxpR3.jpg)
- [Mei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Ppi.jpg)
- [Widowmaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qfFX.jpg)

#### Tank

- [Orisa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u4jT.jpg)
- [Roadhog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kvU5.jpg)

#### Support

- [Ana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH7EL.jpg)
- [Zenyatta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4jDv.jpg)

---

## Disabled Heroes

#### Offense

- None

#### Defense

- Bastion
- Torbjörn

#### Tank

- D.Va
- Reinhardt
- Winston
- Zarya

#### Defense

- Lúcio
- Mercy
- Symmetra